# popup modal form (create||update) in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, bootstrap-modal

I created a page where I can display a list of holidays and a button "add holiday" to create a new holiday but it sends me to another page. so what I'm trying to do is to create a pop-up form so that Instead of displaying the result on another page, I want when the user clicks on the "add holiday" button, there to be a pop-up modal to display the results on the same page.
but it doesn't work .
here is the holiday list code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HolidayService from '../../servicees/HolidayService'
import '../css/list.css';
import { I18nPropvider, LOCALES } from '../../i18nProvider';
import translate from "../../i18nProvider/translate"
import collaboratorService from '../../servicees/CollaborateurServices';
import Fetching from './Fetching'
import {IoTrashSharp, IoSettings,IoAddCircleSharp} from "react-icons/io5";
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import AddHolidayModal from '../add/addHolidayModal';
// holdays list with option give to RH option to change in the list
class Holidaylist extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
                holidays: [],
                fetching: true
        }
        
        this.editHoliday = this.editHoliday.bind(this);
        this.checkRh=this.checkRh.bind(this)
        this.checkRhbtn=this.checkRhbtn.bind(this)
      
    }

    editHoliday(id){
        this.props.history.push(`/admin/holiday/${id}`);
    }
    
   deleteHoliday(id){
       HolidayService.deleteHoliday(id).then( res => {
        this.setState({holidays: this.state.holidays.filter(holiday => holiday.id !== id)});
    });
   }
    componentDidMount(){
        HolidayService.getHoliday().then((res) => {
            this.setState({ holidays: res.data, fetching: false});
        });
    }
    checkRh(x){
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('role')==="RH"){
            return(<td>
                <Button onClick={ () => this.editHoliday(x)} className="showBtn-setting"><IoSettings style={{fontSize:"27px",color:"#1E90FF"}}/> </Button>
                <Button style={{marginLeft: "10px"}} onClick={ () => this.deleteHoliday(x)} className="showBtn-delete"><IoTrashSharp id="trash-btn"/> </Button>
            
            </td>);
               
        }
    }
    checkRhbtn(){
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('role')==="RH"){
            return(
        <div className="btnholiday">
            <button onClick={ ()=>this.setState({modalShow:true})  } className="btn btn-primary" style={{marginRight:'10px'}}><IoAddCircleSharp style={{fontSize:"25px",marginRight:"6px"}}/>{translate("add holiday")}</button>
       </div>);
    }}
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                {this.state.fetching? <Fetching /> : null}
                <br></br>
                <div className = "row">
                {this.checkRhbtn()}
                        <table className = "table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>{translate('Holiday')}</th>
                                    <th>{translate('date')}</th>
                                    <th>{translate('Duration')}</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {   
                                    this.state.holidays.sort(function(a, b) {
                                        var c = new Date(a.date);
                                        var d = new Date(b.date);
                                        return c.getTime()-d.getTime();
                                    }).filter(val=>{
                                        let re = val.country
                                       /* console.log("session: "+typeof(sessionStorage.getItem("country")))
                                        console.log(typeof(re))
                                        console.log(re===sessionStorage.getItem("country"))*/
                                        if(re===sessionStorage.getItem("country")){return val}}).map(
                                        
                                        holiday => 
                                        <tr key = {holiday.id }>
                                            <td> {holiday.name}</td>
                                            <td> {holiday.date}</td>
                                            <td> {holiday.duration}</td>
                                            {this.checkRh(holiday.id)}
                                        </tr>
                                    )
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        
                </div>
            
               </div>
               <AddHolidayModal
               show={this.state.modalShow}
               onHide={()=>this.setState({modalShow:false})}
               mydata="fati"
               />
               </React.Fragment>

        );
    }
}

export default Holidaylist;
```

and the pop-up modal form

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import HolidayService from '../../servicees/HolidayService'
import dateFormat from "dateformat";
import {FormattedMessage} from "react-intl";
import translate from "../../i18nProvider/translate"

class AddHolidayModal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            // step 2
            //act id: this.props.match.params.id,
            name: '',
            date: '',
            duration: '',
            open: false,
            formdata:[]
        }
        this.changenameHandler = this.changenameHandler.bind(this);
        this.changedurationHandler = this.changedurationHandler.bind(this);
        this.changedateHandler = this.changedateHandler.bind(this);
        this.saveOrUpdateHoliday = this.saveOrUpdateHoliday.bind(this);
    }
        // get holiday formation if user click in update
        componentDidMount(){
      
       
            if(this.state.id === 'add'){
                return
            }else{
                HolidayService.getHolidayById(this.state.id).then( (res) =>{
                    let user = res.data;
                    this.setState({
                        id:user.id,
                        name:user.name,
                        date:user.date,
                        duration:user.duration,
                        country:sessionStorage.getItem("country")
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        saveOrUpdateHoliday(event) {
            const formHoliday = {
                name:this.state.name,
                date:this.state.date,
                duration:this.state.duration,
                country:sessionStorage.getItem("country")
            };
        
            if (
                this.state.name==="" ||
                this.state.date ===""||
                this.state.duration ===""
            ) {
              alert("Please fill mandatory filed");
            } else {
              if (this.state.formdata.filter(holiday => holiday.name === formHoliday.name).length > 0) {
                // update item
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                  formdata: prevState.formdata.map(holiday => {
                    if (holiday.name === formHoliday.name)
                      return formHoliday;
                    else
                      return holiday;
                  })
                }));
        
              } else {
                // add new item
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                  formdata: prevState.formdata.concat(formHoliday)
                }));
        
              }
        
              alert("form submited: ");
        
              this.setState({
                name: '',
                date: '',
                duration: ''
              });
            }
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        changenameHandler= (event) => {
            this.setState({name: event.target.value});
        }
    
        changedurationHandler= (event) => {
            this.setState({duration: event.target.value});
        }
    
        changedateHandler= (event) => {
            this.setState({date: dateFormat(event.target.value, "yyyy-mm-dd")});
            
        }
    
        handleClose = (event, reason) => {
            if (reason === 'clickaway') {
              return;
        }
            this.setState({open:false});
        };

    render(){

        return (
            <Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.onHide}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton><Modal.Title>Add a Holiday</Modal.Title></Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                    <Card>
                        <Card.Body>
                        {
                        <div className = "row">
                                <div className = "card-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label>{translate('Name')}: </label>
                                            <FormattedMessage id="Name">
                                              {message =>  <input placeholder={message} name="name" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.name} onChange={this.changenameHandler}/>}
                                            </FormattedMessage>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> {translate('date')} </label>
                                            <FormattedMessage id="date">
                                              {message =>  <input placeholder={message} name="date" className="form-control" 
                                               type="date" value={this.state.date} onChange={this.changedateHandler}/>}
                                            </FormattedMessage>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> {translate('duration')} </label>
                                            <FormattedMessage id="duration">
                                              {message => <input placeholder={message} name="duration" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.duration} onChange={this.changedurationHandler}/>}
                                            </FormattedMessage>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
}
                    </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.saveOrUpdateHoliday}>{translate('Save')}</Button>
                                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button> 
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
        );
    }
}
export default AddHolidayModal;
```

Comment: you should pass setState from Holidaylist  to Modal, then you can update holidays state with new holiday